# How do you get an item from a dropdown and input it as text?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

So I'm using bootstrap form helpers to make selecting a country and region easier. Here is some of the code. I want to take this and input it into my db. It currently won't.

```
       <div id="countries_states2" class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries" data-country="US" data-flags="true" name="country">
        <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-states" data-country="countries_states2" name="stateOrProvince">
        <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, this does

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="ironbat@example.com">
    </div>
```

How can I enter the former into the form without wrecking the formatting (its very pretty :) )

As a template, here is a similar setup/strategy:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: What kind of db is it?  What are you using to connect to it?  Can you include the source that does the db insertion for the e-mail address?

Comment: not really enough information here but - input needs a name property for the server to recognise the field .. does that help?

Comment: Its mongo and using a mongodb as a service provider (just a user:password unique url). Very similar to scotch.io's user auth https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local